# Broken JQuery Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

My tabs are created using PHP so I do not want a set width per tabswitcher tab. Due to this I am trying to add up the total width of the tabswitcher so I can set the width then apply a `margin:0 auto;`.

Alerting the `var width` is returning NaN. This is my first loop attempt, probably screwed up somewhere! (obviously...)

**JQuery**

```
var width;
var NumOfTabs = $('.TabSwitcher .Tab').length;
var count = 1;
while (count < NumOfTabs){
    width = width + $('.TabSwitcher .Tab:nth-child(' + count + ')').width();
    count++;
}
width = width + (NumOfTabs * 4) // Add passing
$('.TabSwitcher').css({'width': width + 'px'});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="TabSwitcher">
    <div class="Tab Active" id="Page_1">1</div>
    <div class="Tab" id="Page_2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see any `var margin`, is it `var width` instead?

Comment: `width` is initially `NULL`. Hard to add `NULL`.

Comment: Which `var margin` !! You mean `var width`?

Comment: Sorry, let me edit, that was it's old name!!

Comment: `$('.TabSwitcher .Tab:nth-child(' + count + ')')` talk about bad performance

Comment: Width is initially null but then my loop is meant to count all the tab widths and then after add the padding total then set the width of the tabswitcher

Comment: @TimMarshall ok good, well then, Tomanow is right (with the exception that the var is `undefined`). just set it to 0 : `var width = 0;`

Comment: @Tomanow It is not null, it is undefined.

Comment: Yes @epascarello I have stated this is my first JQuery loop and it is not working so obviously I have gone wrong. You may have pointed out an error but a solution would be nice.

Comment: For the record, `while (condition) { }` is not a "jquery" loop; it's just javascript. jQuery has a `$().each` method that might suit you more.

Comment: `$('.TabSwitcher .Tab').each(function(index, el) { el.css(); };` won't this be more efficient?

Comment: So define it: `var width = 0;`

Comment: Are you going to argue about undefined/null and other things? Try to answer.

Comment: @wlin looks good but how does that add all the widths?

Comment: `$('.TabSwitcher .Tab').length * $('.TabSwitcher .Tab').first().width()` should do the trick.

Comment: @AdrianIftode I see no arguing going on here. I even see an answer, twice.

Comment: Maybe this: `width = parseInt(width) + parseInt($('.TabSwitcher .Tab:nth-child(' + count + ')').width());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider using jQuery's handy `each` method, like so:

```
var width = 0;
var tabs = $('.TabSwitcher .Tab');
tabs.each(function(index, tab) {
    width += $(tab).width();
});
width += (tabs.length * 4); // Add padding
$('.TabSwitcher').css({'width': width + 'px'});
```

You should also note that `width` MUST be instantiated to `0`. Otherwise, adding to it will only produce `NaN`.

Comment: By the way, though this is a nice suggestion, buried in your answer is the fact that the only bug the OP had was that they didn't initialize `width` to 0

Comment: @Regent Thanks! I skimmed right over that, but it's nicer with the `+=`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do not keep looking things up. All that will do is make it slow since you keep looking up the same thing, over and over.

```
var width = 0;  //you original issue, initialize it with a start value
var tabs = $('.TabSwitcher .Tab'); //store it do not look it up over and over
var numOfTabs = tabs.length;

tabs.each( function() {  //use each to loop
    width = width + $(this).width();  //"this" is the current tab
});

width = width + (numOfTabs * 4) // Add padding
$('.TabSwitcher').css({'width': width + 'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/drk01j1L/

```
var width = 0;

$('.TabSwitcher .Tab').each(
function(index, el) {
   width = width + $(el).width();
}
);

$('.answer').html(width);
```

here, you use each to find all width add them together.